# Filtering data Horizontally in google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have attempted to apply horizontal filtering to data in Google Sheets, but have encountered difficulty including the first column in the formula. My aim is for any column name selected from the dropdown list to display that name along with the first column, which is labeled "code". Additionally,

I only want to filter values that have content, disregarding those that are blank or contain a "-".

```
=FILTER(Data!A1:N30,Data!A1:N1=G2)
```

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17_K3SmDUvlG1czw3xkNgbed_r2BNMn_4tpCaTRjx1yw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,filter(Data!A:N,(Data!A1:N1="Code")+(Data!A1:N1=F1)),
   filter(Σ,index(Σ,,2)<>"",index(Σ,,2)<>"-"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much i want to remove the cells with `0` value as well

Comment: you can add extra conditions alongside `-`, `blanks` such as `index(Σ,,2)<>0`

Comment: I got you, Thanks once again.

Comment: Updated the formula in `Cell P4`